# Algorithm for finding largest unique combination of items from an array

Tags: algorithm, combinations, subset

Here's a simplified data set that I'm using that covers my basic tripping points.
Id, Date, Location

```
(1, Jan 1, LA), (2, Jan 2, LA), (3, Jan 2, LA), (4, Jan 2, NY), (5, Jan 3, LA), (6, Jan 5, LA)
```

What I'd like to find is the largest unique combination sets, restricted to a date range, and grouped by location.

So with that data above and input of

```
date_range = 3
```

My output (of id's for simplicity) should be:

```
1,2,3,5
4,
5,6
```

So a combination of 1,2,3 would not be included as it's a subset of 1,2,3,5

My first attempt was to find all possible combinations and eliminate subsets after. I couldn't find a great solution here. It seems really inefficient.

Second attempt was something along the lines of:

```
Loop through each item
 Find largest combination
```

This seems to work better but still creates duplicates. For example it would return the following:

```
1,2,3,5
2,3,5
3,5
4
5,6
6
```

I don't have a massive dataset this needs to work on, 1000 items would be the high end but performance will be noticeable. Maybe I'm overcomplicating this and I need to focus on eliminating the subsets efficiently instead of doing it all in one pass?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the *shortest code necessary to reproduce it* in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [mcve]

Comment: Seems like you just need another step in your current algorithm:

Loop through each item
   Determine largest set
   if set isn't part of the the listOfSets and isn't a subset of any list in listOfSets
        Add set to listOfSets

However, I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "unique".  Your example seems to imply that 2 and 3 are unique despite having the same date and location.

Answer (score 1):

First partition by location, then sort each location by date.
Given a date range of N days, walk through the sorted data, mapping it to an array of tuples like

`(count(entries where date in (this_date-N:this_date)), [indexes])`

You should be able to do this in linear time by maintaining two indexes: 'today' and 'N days ago'.

Now simply find the max count, then remove any entries for the previous N days.  Repeat until the array is empty.